# R shiny module with save button

Tags: r, shiny

I am setting up a module, with the purpose of having two data tables in the same app, in different tabs.
I would like to be able to edit and save each table separately.
In my code, only the first "save" button works, and it saves both data tables.

Ideally, each save button should work and save only the corresponding table.

Important:  I use the modified version of [DTedit](https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit):

```
devtools::install_github('DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit@2.2.1')
```

Here is my problematic code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DTedit)

myModuleUI <- function(id,nam) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  shiny::tagList(
    
    br(),
    
    ##### needs corrections!!
    
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("XXX",  dteditmodUI(ns(nam)),actionButton(ns("reset"), "Reset to Saved", styleclass = "warning"),  actionButton(ns("saveBtn"), label = "save"),  br(),
                         id=ns('tabset'), type = 'tabs')
    )
  )
  ####
}

myModule <- function(input, output, session,df,nam,taby,wb) {
  
  dfr=reactiveVal()
  dfr(df)
  
  
  Grocery_List_Results <- shiny::callModule(
    dteditmod,
    id = nam,
    thedata =dfr)
    
   

  # ### save  part
  
  savd = data.frame(isolate(dfr()))
  
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, {
    
    print("Q")
    ## Add worksheets
    st = paste(taby,as.character(unclass(Sys.time())),sep="_")
    addWorksheet(wb, st)
    
    writeData(x = Grocery_List_Results$thedata,
              wb = wb,
              sheet = st)
    
    
    saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = T)
    
    savd <<- Grocery_List_Results$thedata
    
    
    shinyalert(title = "Saved!", type = "success")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    dfr(savd)
    print(dfr)
    
    shinyalert(title = "Reset to saved data!", type = "info")
  })
  
  
}






########

ui <- fluidPage(
  h3('Grocery List'),
  myModuleUI('myModule1',nam="groc"),br(),
  myModuleUI('myModule1',nam="groc2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df= data.frame(
    Buy = c('Tea', 'Biscuits', 'Apples',"Tea","Apples"),
    Quantity = c(7, 2, 5,9,44),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
  file = "AICs.xlsx"
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
  
  
  shiny::callModule(myModule, 'myModule1',nam="groc",df=df,taby="Tea",wb)
  shiny::callModule(myModule, 'myModule1',nam="groc2",df=df,taby="Apples",wb)
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Appreciate your time!

Comment: I couldn't debug the code fully, since I don't have access to the Excel file the code references, but one possible problem is that...

* the calls to `myModuleUI` should have parameters `myModule1` for the first call and (for example) `myModule2` for the second call

* likewise, the `callModule` call should have parameter `myModule1` for the first call, and then `myModule2` for the second call.

Answer (score 0):

At long last,
and thanks to this [thread](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2486),
it ***seems*** that I managed to solve this:

```
library( "openxlsx"  )
library("shiny" )    
library(shinyalert)
library(shinysky)
library(DTedit) ## used the modified version from https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit
#installed with devtools::install_github('DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit@2.2.1')


results_2_UI <- function(id,nam) {
  useShinyalert()
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    title = "Export1",
      dteditmodUI(ns(nam)),
    actionButton(ns("reset"), "Reset to Saved", styleclass = "warning"),  actionButton(ns("saveBtn"), label = "save")
    
  )
}

results_3_UI <- function(id,nam) {
  useShinyalert()
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    title = "Export2",
    dteditmodUI(ns(nam)),
    actionButton(ns("reset"), "Reset to Saved", styleclass = "warning"),  actionButton(ns("saveBtn"), label = "save")
    
  )
}

results <- function(input, output, session,df,nam,taby,wb) {
  ## do some complicated data transformations
  dfr=reactiveVal()
  dfr(df)
  
  
  Grocery_List_Results <- shiny::callModule(
    dteditmod,
    id = nam,
    thedata =dfr)
  
  
  
  # ### save  part
  
  savd = data.frame(isolate(dfr()))
  
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, {
    
    print("Q")
    ## Add worksheets
    st = paste(taby,as.character(unclass(Sys.time())),sep="_")
    addWorksheet(wb, st)
    
    writeData(x = Grocery_List_Results$thedata,
              wb = wb,
              sheet = st)
    
    
    saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = T)
    
    savd <<- Grocery_List_Results$thedata
    
    
    shinyalert :: shinyalert(title = "Saved!", type = "success")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    dfr(savd)
    print(dfr)
    
    shinyalert::shinyalert(title = "Reset to saved data!", type = "info")
  })
  

}
### module end

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabs",
 
    # results_1_UI(id = "test1"),
    results_2_UI(id = "test2",nam="groc"),
    results_3_UI(id = "test3",nam="groc2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df= data.frame(
    Buy = c('Tea', 'Biscuits', 'Apples',"Tea","Apples"),
    Quantity = c(7, 2, 5,9,44),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
  file = "AICs.xlsx"
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
  
 
  callModule(
    module = results,
    id = "test2",
    nam="groc",df=df,taby="groc",wb=wb
  )
  
  callModule(
    module = results,
    id = "test3",
    nam="groc2",df=df,taby="groc2",wb=wb
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Fingers crossed, it is OK!